How can I view/kill vscode "launch" processes?
I guess I keep coming into some weird state where the run crashes but vscode "launch" is still running for some reason, and I don't want to kill the whole program to get rid of that process. I am getting a pop-up saying 'Launch' is already running. Do you want to start another instance? whenever I click F5 to build and run my current project.

I couldn't find a clear task manager and I don't know how can I just kill the running 'launch' or replace it when I build again. Any thoughts?
